# Push and slice multiple times in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to do a push a new value to a capped array:

```
db.messages.insert({name:"test1"})
db.messages.update({name:"test1"}, {"$push":{"output": {"$each": ["test1"], "$slice": -10}}})
db.messages.update({name:"test1"}, {"$push":{"output": {"$each": ["test2"], "$slice": -10}}})
```

So, the first time I execute the update, I get what I expect:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51d482ee7252cb3f7eb81ac1"),
"name" : "test1",
"output" : [
    "test1"
]
}
```

But, after the second update, I get the following:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51d482ee7252cb3f7eb81ac1"),
"name" : "test1",
"output" : [
    "test1",
    {
        "$each" : [
            "test2"
        ],
        "$slice" : -10
    }
]
}
```

When I expected the following:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51d482ee7252cb3f7eb81ac1"),
"name" : "test1",
"output" : [
    "test1",
    "test2"
]
}
```

Probably I'm not understanding how to use $push with $slice, but looking at the documentation I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong. How can achive adding a new element to a capped array?

Comment: I tried the exact same command that you mentioned in my mongo shell and I was able to get the expected output. Are you using the db.messages.find() query to look at the collection?

Comment: Yes, I'm using db.messages.find(). However, now I read your comment, I think I know what's going on: I'm using version 2.2, where documentation indicates that $slice modifier is available to use with $push in 2.4. Thanks!

Comment: aha ! Good find. Try using the next version and then let us know here if it works. You can then create your own answer an accept it so that it would be useful for future readers who encounter the same problem !!:)

Comment: @sherry-get tested that and works fine in 2.4, so that was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you observed can be reproduced in MongoDB version 2.2.  Your example works as expected in MongoDB version 2.4

```
> db.things.insert({name:"test1"})
> db.things.update({name:"test1"}, {"$push":{"output": {"$each": ["test1"], "$slice": -10}}})
> db.things.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51d489f730d17c1ffbd6ff9f"), "name" : "test1", "output" : [  "test1" ] }
> db.things.update({name:"test1"}, {"$push":{"output": {"$each": ["test2"], "$slice": -10}}})
> db.things.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("51d489f730d17c1ffbd6ff9f"), "name" : "test1", "output" : [  "test1",  "test2" ] }
```

From the documentation, $each support to $push operator was added in version 2.4

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/each/#op._S_each

Most likely you are using an older version of MongoDB that does not support $each with the $push operator.  What version of MongoDB are you running?  You can find out the version you are running by using the following command from MongoDB shell.

```
>db.version()
```

To get the latest release of MongoDB, please go to the following link.

http://www.mongodb.org/downloads